# jqr package not matching results from jq

Tags: r, jq, jsonlite, rjson, rjsonio

```
person <- GET(
  "https://api.secure.com/v4/people/111322450?$expand=customFields",
  accept_json(),
  add_headers(Accept = 'application/json',
    Authorization = APIKey)
)

capture <- content(person)

dput(capture)

capture <- list(vanId = 111322450L, firstName = "Joe", lastName = "Smith", 
    middleName = NULL, suffix = NULL, title = "Mr.", contactMode = "Person", 
    organizationContactCommonName = NULL, organizationContactOfficialName = NULL, 
    salutation = "Joe", formalSalutation = "Mr. Smith", additionalSalutation = NULL, 
    preferredPronoun = NULL, envelopeName = "Joe Smith", formalEnvelopeName = "Mr. Joe Smith", 
    additionalEnvelopeName = NULL, contactMethodPreferenceCode = NULL, 
    nickname = NULL, website = NULL, professionalSuffix = NULL, 
    party = NULL, employer = NULL, occupation = NULL, sex = NULL, 
    dateOfBirth = NULL, selfReportedRace = NULL, selfReportedEthnicity = NULL, 
    selfReportedRaces = NULL, selfReportedEthnicities = NULL, 
    selfReportedGenders = NULL, selfReportedSexualOrientations = NULL, 
    selfReportedLanguagePreference = NULL, emails = NULL, phones = NULL, 
    addresses = NULL, recordedAddresses = NULL, identifiers = NULL, 
    codes = NULL, customFields = list(list(customField = list(
        customFieldId = 54L, customFieldParentId = NULL, customFieldName = "If you're in college, which college?", 
        customFieldGroupId = 12L, customFieldGroupName = "College", 
        customFieldGroupType = "Contacts", customFieldTypeId = "T", 
        isEditable = TRUE, maxTextboxCharacters = 75L, availableValues = NULL, 
        isExportable = TRUE), customFieldId = 54L, customFieldGroupId = 12L, 
        assignedValue = NULL), list(customField = list(customFieldId = 63L, 
        customFieldParentId = NULL, customFieldName = "Graduation Year", 
        customFieldGroupId = 12L, customFieldGroupName = "College", 
        customFieldGroupType = "Contacts", customFieldTypeId = "S", 
        isEditable = TRUE, maxTextboxCharacters = NULL, availableValues = list(
            list(id = 1L, name = "2017", parentValueId = NULL), 
            list(id = 2L, name = "2018", parentValueId = NULL), 
            list(id = 3L, name = "2019", parentValueId = NULL), 
            list(id = 4L, name = "2020", parentValueId = NULL), 
            list(id = 5L, name = "2021", parentValueId = NULL), 
            list(id = 6L, name = "2022", parentValueId = NULL), 
            list(id = 7L, name = "2023", parentValueId = NULL), 
            list(id = 8L, name = "2024", parentValueId = NULL), 
            list(id = 11L, name = "2025", parentValueId = NULL), 
            list(id = 12L, name = "2026", parentValueId = NULL), 
            list(id = 9L, name = "Already graduated", parentValueId = NULL), 
            list(id = 10L, name = "Not applicable", parentValueId = NULL)), 
        isExportable = TRUE), customFieldId = 63L, customFieldGroupId = 12L, 
        assignedValue = NULL), list(customField = list(customFieldId = 81L, 
        customFieldParentId = NULL, customFieldName = "School Organization", 
        customFieldGroupId = 12L, customFieldGroupName = "College", 
        customFieldGroupType = "Contacts", customFieldTypeId = "S", 
        isEditable = TRUE, maxTextboxCharacters = NULL, availableValues = list(
            list(id = 1L, name = "Administration/Administrators", 
                parentValueId = NULL), list(id = 2L, name = "Class Representatives", 
                parentValueId = NULL), list(id = 3L, name = "Greek Life", 
                parentValueId = NULL), list(id = 4L, name = "Other", 
                parentValueId = NULL), list(id = 5L, name = "Student Clubs", 
                parentValueId = NULL)), isExportable = TRUE), 
        customFieldId = 81L, customFieldGroupId = 12L, assignedValue = NULL), 
        list(customField = list(customFieldId = 82L, customFieldParentId = NULL, 
            customFieldName = "School Organization Name", customFieldGroupId = 12L, 
            customFieldGroupName = "College", customFieldGroupType = "Contacts", 
            customFieldTypeId = "T", isEditable = TRUE, maxTextboxCharacters = 75L, 
            availableValues = NULL, isExportable = TRUE), customFieldId = 82L, 
            customFieldGroupId = 12L, assignedValue = NULL), 
        list(customField = list(customFieldId = 83L, customFieldParentId = NULL, 
            customFieldName = "Gender", customFieldGroupId = 36L, 
            customFieldGroupName = "Demographics", customFieldGroupType = "Contacts", 
            customFieldTypeId = "T", isEditable = TRUE, maxTextboxCharacters = 75L, 
            availableValues = NULL, isExportable = TRUE), customFieldId = 83L, 
            customFieldGroupId = 36L, assignedValue = "Male"), 
        list(customField = list(customFieldId = 84L, customFieldParentId = NULL, 
            customFieldName = "Race", customFieldGroupId = 36L, 
            customFieldGroupName = "Demographics", customFieldGroupType = "Contacts", 
            customFieldTypeId = "T", isEditable = TRUE, maxTextboxCharacters = 75L, 
            availableValues = NULL, isExportable = TRUE), customFieldId = 84L, 
            customFieldGroupId = 36L, assignedValue = "Caucasian"), 
        list(customField = list(customFieldId = 85L, customFieldParentId = NULL, 
            customFieldName = "Age", customFieldGroupId = 36L, 
            customFieldGroupName = "Demographics", customFieldGroupType = "Contacts", 
            customFieldTypeId = "T", isEditable = TRUE, maxTextboxCharacters = 75L, 
            availableValues = NULL, isExportable = TRUE), customFieldId = 85L, 
            customFieldGroupId = 36L, assignedValue = "31"), 
        list(customField = list(customFieldId = 70L, customFieldParentId = NULL, 
            customFieldName = "Are you over 21?", customFieldGroupId = 16L, 
            customFieldGroupName = "RSVPs", customFieldGroupType = "Contacts", 
            customFieldTypeId = "S", isEditable = TRUE, maxTextboxCharacters = NULL, 
            availableValues = list(list(id = 1L, name = "no", 
                parentValueId = NULL), list(id = 2L, name = "yes", 
                parentValueId = NULL)), isExportable = TRUE), 
            customFieldId = 70L, customFieldGroupId = 16L, assignedValue = NULL), 
        list(customField = list(customFieldId = 12L, customFieldParentId = NULL, 
            customFieldName = "Opt-in to SMS messages", customFieldGroupId = 9L, 
            customFieldGroupName = "SMS OPT", customFieldGroupType = "Contacts", 
            customFieldTypeId = "B", isEditable = TRUE, maxTextboxCharacters = NULL, 
            availableValues = NULL, isExportable = FALSE), customFieldId = 12L, 
            customFieldGroupId = 9L, assignedValue = NULL), list(
            customField = list(customFieldId = 75L, customFieldParentId = NULL, 
                customFieldName = "Instagram Handle", customFieldGroupId = 34L, 
                customFieldGroupName = "Social Media", customFieldGroupType = "Contacts", 
                customFieldTypeId = "T", isEditable = TRUE, maxTextboxCharacters = 75L, 
                availableValues = NULL, isExportable = TRUE), 
            customFieldId = 75L, customFieldGroupId = 34L, assignedValue = NULL), 
        list(customField = list(customFieldId = 79L, customFieldParentId = NULL, 
            customFieldName = "Facebook Username", customFieldGroupId = 34L, 
            customFieldGroupName = "Social Media", customFieldGroupType = "Contacts", 
            customFieldTypeId = "T", isEditable = TRUE, maxTextboxCharacters = 75L, 
            availableValues = NULL, isExportable = TRUE), customFieldId = 79L, 
            customFieldGroupId = 34L, assignedValue = NULL), 
        list(customField = list(customFieldId = 66L, customFieldParentId = NULL, 
            customFieldName = "Upload ", customFieldGroupId = 31L, 
            customFieldGroupName = "Story Collection", customFieldGroupType = "Contacts", 
            customFieldTypeId = "S", isEditable = TRUE, maxTextboxCharacters = NULL, 
            availableValues = list(), isExportable = TRUE), customFieldId = 66L, 
            customFieldGroupId = 31L, assignedValue = NULL), 
        list(customField = list(customFieldId = 65L, customFieldParentId = NULL, 
            customFieldName = "Story Collection ", customFieldGroupId = 31L, 
            customFieldGroupName = "Story Collection", customFieldGroupType = "Contacts", 
            customFieldTypeId = "B", isEditable = TRUE, maxTextboxCharacters = NULL, 
            availableValues = NULL, isExportable = TRUE), customFieldId = 65L, 
            customFieldGroupId = 31L, assignedValue = NULL), 
        list(customField = list(customFieldId = 64L, customFieldParentId = NULL, 
            customFieldName = "Story Upload", customFieldGroupId = 31L, 
            customFieldGroupName = "Story Collection", customFieldGroupType = "Contacts", 
            customFieldTypeId = "T", isEditable = TRUE, maxTextboxCharacters = 75L, 
            availableValues = NULL, isExportable = TRUE), customFieldId = 64L, 
            customFieldGroupId = 31L, assignedValue = NULL), 
        list(customField = list(customFieldId = 13L, customFieldParentId = NULL, 
            customFieldName = "I would like to volunteer.", customFieldGroupId = 10L, 
            customFieldGroupName = "Volunteer", customFieldGroupType = "Contacts", 
            customFieldTypeId = "B", isEditable = TRUE, maxTextboxCharacters = NULL, 
            availableValues = NULL, isExportable = FALSE), customFieldId = 13L, 
            customFieldGroupId = 10L, assignedValue = NULL), 
        list(customField = list(customFieldId = 38L, customFieldParentId = NULL, 
            customFieldName = "Text Opt-in (old)", customFieldGroupId = 10L, 
            customFieldGroupName = "Volunteer", customFieldGroupType = "Contacts", 
            customFieldTypeId = "B", isEditable = TRUE, maxTextboxCharacters = NULL, 
            availableValues = NULL, isExportable = TRUE), customFieldId = 38L, 
            customFieldGroupId = 10L, assignedValue = NULL), 
        list(customField = list(customFieldId = 62L, customFieldParentId = NULL, 
            customFieldName = "Are you a high school student?", 
            customFieldGroupId = 10L, customFieldGroupName = "Volunteer", 
            customFieldGroupType = "Contacts", customFieldTypeId = "B", 
            isEditable = TRUE, maxTextboxCharacters = NULL, availableValues = NULL, 
            isExportable = TRUE), customFieldId = 62L, customFieldGroupId = 10L, 
            assignedValue = NULL), list(customField = list(customFieldId = 67L, 
            customFieldParentId = NULL, customFieldName = "Have you done any sort of calling, texting, or door-knocking for a political or issue campaign?", 
            customFieldGroupId = 10L, customFieldGroupName = "Volunteer", 
            customFieldGroupType = "Contacts", customFieldTypeId = "S", 
            isEditable = TRUE, maxTextboxCharacters = NULL, availableValues = list(
                list(id = 1L, name = "No", parentValueId = NULL), 
                list(id = 2L, name = "Yes", parentValueId = NULL)), 
            isExportable = TRUE), customFieldId = 67L, customFieldGroupId = 10L, 
            assignedValue = NULL), list(customField = list(customFieldId = 68L, 
            customFieldParentId = NULL, customFieldName = "Check here if you are a Spanish speaker", 
            customFieldGroupId = 10L, customFieldGroupName = "Volunteer", 
            customFieldGroupType = "Contacts", customFieldTypeId = "B", 
            isEditable = TRUE, maxTextboxCharacters = NULL, availableValues = NULL, 
            isExportable = TRUE), customFieldId = 68L, customFieldGroupId = 10L, 
            assignedValue = NULL), list(customField = list(customFieldId = 69L, 
            customFieldParentId = NULL, customFieldName = "Best way to remind you of your shift?", 
            customFieldGroupId = 10L, customFieldGroupName = "Volunteer", 
            customFieldGroupType = "Contacts", customFieldTypeId = "S", 
            isEditable = TRUE, maxTextboxCharacters = NULL, availableValues = list(
                list(id = 1L, name = "Email", parentValueId = NULL), 
                list(id = 2L, name = "Phone call", parentValueId = NULL), 
                list(id = 3L, name = "Text", parentValueId = NULL)), 
            isExportable = TRUE), customFieldId = 69L, customFieldGroupId = 10L, 
            assignedValue = NULL), list(customField = list(customFieldId = 76L, 
            customFieldParentId = NULL, customFieldName = "Vote Tripling Contact 1", 
            customFieldGroupId = 35L, customFieldGroupName = "Vote Tripling", 
            customFieldGroupType = "Contacts", customFieldTypeId = "T", 
            isEditable = TRUE, maxTextboxCharacters = 75L, availableValues = NULL, 
            isExportable = TRUE), customFieldId = 76L, customFieldGroupId = 35L, 
            assignedValue = NULL), list(customField = list(customFieldId = 77L, 
            customFieldParentId = NULL, customFieldName = "Vote Tripling Contact 2", 
            customFieldGroupId = 35L, customFieldGroupName = "Vote Tripling", 
            customFieldGroupType = "Contacts", customFieldTypeId = "T", 
            isEditable = TRUE, maxTextboxCharacters = 75L, availableValues = NULL, 
            isExportable = TRUE), customFieldId = 77L, customFieldGroupId = 35L, 
            assignedValue = NULL), list(customField = list(customFieldId = 78L, 
            customFieldParentId = NULL, customFieldName = "Vote Tripling Contact 3", 
            customFieldGroupId = 35L, customFieldGroupName = "Vote Tripling", 
            customFieldGroupType = "Contacts", customFieldTypeId = "T", 
            isEditable = TRUE, maxTextboxCharacters = 75L, availableValues = NULL, 
            isExportable = TRUE), customFieldId = 78L, customFieldGroupId = 35L, 
            assignedValue = NULL), list(customField = list(customFieldId = 71L, 
            customFieldParentId = NULL, customFieldName = "Yes, send me a text on election day to remind me to vote", 
            customFieldGroupId = 32L, customFieldGroupName = "Voting", 
            customFieldGroupType = "Contacts", customFieldTypeId = "B", 
            isEditable = TRUE, maxTextboxCharacters = NULL, availableValues = NULL, 
            isExportable = TRUE), customFieldId = 71L, customFieldGroupId = 32L, 
            assignedValue = NULL), list(customField = list(customFieldId = 72L, 
            customFieldParentId = NULL, customFieldName = "how do you plan on voting?", 
            customFieldGroupId = 32L, customFieldGroupName = "Voting", 
            customFieldGroupType = "Contacts", customFieldTypeId = "T", 
            isEditable = TRUE, maxTextboxCharacters = 75L, availableValues = NULL, 
            isExportable = TRUE), customFieldId = 72L, customFieldGroupId = 32L, 
            assignedValue = NULL), list(customField = list(customFieldId = 80L, 
            customFieldParentId = NULL, customFieldName = "I'm a first-time voter!", 
            customFieldGroupId = 32L, customFieldGroupName = "Voting", 
            customFieldGroupType = "Contacts", customFieldTypeId = "B", 
            isEditable = TRUE, maxTextboxCharacters = NULL, availableValues = NULL, 
            isExportable = TRUE), customFieldId = 80L, customFieldGroupId = 32L, 
            assignedValue = NULL)), primaryCustomField = NULL, 
    contributionSummary = NULL, suppressions = NULL, caseworkCases = NULL, 
    caseworkIssues = NULL, caseworkStories = NULL, notes = NULL, 
    scores = NULL, customProperties = NULL, electionRecords = NULL, 
    membershipStatus = NULL, organizationRoles = NULL, districts = NULL, 
    surveyQuestionResponses = NULL, finderNumber = NULL, biographyImageUrl = NULL, 
    primaryContact = NULL)
```

First I convert it to a JSON:

```
capture_json <- rjson::toJSON(capture)
```

Then I narrow it to only include `.customFields` and then I filter it on which `customFieldId`'s I want:

```
capture_jq <- capture_json %>% jqr::jq('.customFields') %>% jq('.[] | select(.customField.customFieldId | IN(83,84,85))')
```

Using that JSON data, I'm trying to extract the values listed in the `assignedValue` field. When I use the jq tool and filter by `.[]|.assignedValue` it returns the values I want:

```
"Male"
"Caucasian"
"31"
```

[You can see for yourself in this link.](https://jqplay.org/s/ymxW95jr2d)

In my R script, the JSON data is stored in a variable called `capture_jq` and then I run this script:

```
assigned_values <- capture_jq %>% jq('.[]|."assignedValue"')
```

But when I run that script, all it does is return null values that look like this:

```
[
    null,
    null,
    null
]
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is it working fine in the jqplay link I provided above but not using the `jqr` package in R?

Comment: @akrun please check the new reproducible script

Comment: I got it, but I think what you are getting in `capture` for those "assignedValue" is `"null"`.  It could be related to the GET call

Comment: But it doesn't say `null` in the dput. You can see for example: `assignedValue = "Caucasian"`

Furthermore, if I run say `capture_jq %>% jq('.[]|."customFieldId"') ` it does return values

Comment: You can look at the values in `capture` `$customFields[[25]]$customField$availableValues
NULL`

Comment: I don't get it. If you check my dput output, you can clearly see that the values aren't NULL. To help you sort out the big JSON blob, just search this page for "**" to show you what I'm talking about

Comment: You may check =your dput itself it shows `customFieldGroupId = 12L, assignedValue = NULL)`

Comment: Right but that's not what I'm trying to extract. Those values are irrelevant to what I'm trying to extract. If you run `capture_json <- rjson::toJSON(capture)` followed by `capture_jq <- capture_json %>% jqr::jq('.customFields') %>% jq('.[] | select(.customField.customFieldId | IN(83,84,85))')` you'll see what I'm talking about. I'm trying to get `assignedValue` from from `customFieldId` 83, 84, and, 85

Comment: I get `capture_jq %>% jq('."assignedValue"')
[
    "Male",
    "Caucasian",
    "31"
]`

Comment: Ohhhh it was because I was running `capture_jq %>% jq('.[]|."assignedValue"')`. If I run `capture_jq %>% jq('."assignedValue"')` it works.

Comment: Thank you for your help and patience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can change the syntax to as the structure was slightly different compared to the one OP run it on the site

```
> capture_jq %>% jq('."assignedValue"')
[
    "Male",
    "Caucasian",
    "31"
]
```